# xmlHttpRequest via Google Chrome Extension, simple POST to .php page

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

I have a basic Google Chrome Extension that records some data and I want the data to be sent via xmlHttpRequest to an external php page (with POST).

In my permissions page (manifest.json), I have:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://www.mywebsite.com/",
    "https://www.mywebsite.com/",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/*"
],
```

In my content script, I have the code:

```
if (var1 && var2) {
    var xmlhttp = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/datalogger.php";
    var params = "var1="+var1+"var1="+var1;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

However (you guessed it!) my code won't work.
Can anyone figure out what's wrong with it?

Comment: (this is not the answer to your question) but why are u doing ActiveXObject when it's a chrome extension.

Comment: Is that wrong? I have little to no experience with writing google-chrome-extensions.

Comment: well it's not wrong, it's just that chrome has XMLHttpRequest object and ActiveXObject is for IE or Microsoft (older) browsers, hence you don't really need that check.

Comment: well the code looks ok, the only thing that comes to mind is that, is the `var1` and `var2` defined or contain the value coz that might prevent it to enter the `if` itself

Comment: when you say it doesn't work... does the page not get requested at all or is it just that the params are not received at the other end.... also, I notice that you have written: "var1="+var1+"var1="+var1; rather than "var1="+var1+"var2="+var2; ... Is that how it is in your actual script or just your question?

Answer (score 0):

`http://www.mywebsite.com/` is a [match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) that matches only the root part of the domain (i.e., the path "`/`"). You should use `http://www.mywebsite.com/*` with a final star instead. You should apply that final to star to all of your host permissions.